# Receiving headers sent from SERVER to CLIENT in NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, backbone.js

I am really in need of your help. When a header is being sent from the server side, through res.writeHead and res.end, how do you get the data in the CLIENT SIDE and populate it in the html?

**Details** : I am using Node, and Backbone.js. 
Codes :

**SERVER-SIDE CODE** :

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain','Error':'err'});
res.end();
```

What do i write in the client side? or in the html page itself? Please do enlighten me.

Comment: That depends on your client side code.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, making up HTTP headers is a bad idea. Use standard status codes and put extended error messages in the response body.

Comment: Where are you trying to get the headers? When fetching a collection? Updating a model?

Comment: If you're using ajax [`XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeader()) otherwise ???

Comment: I'd like to use the data sent by the headers in the client side, like for example appending the data to a div.

Comment: Can any of you suggest ANY way to use the data sent by the server in the html page itself??

Comment: I am really desperate :(

Comment: There are several problems with this question.  First of all, it's an XY problem (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Second of all, you don't specify how you intend to receive the headers above - will it be through HTTP or as an AJAX response?  Third of all, you don't mention what data it is that you want to access.  Finally, you give no details whatsoever as to how you are writing your client-side code.  Saying that you are "using Backbone" is almost as broad as saying that you are using Javascript.  It could mean a million different things.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Backbone's methods that fire off Ajax requests ([like Collection.fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)) will return a [jQuery XMLHttpRequest object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) (assuming you're using jQuery). If you really need to look at the headers, you can do something like the following:

```
collection.fetch().done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var header = jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders();
    // do stuff with the headers
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for you reply. But i would really like to put the code in the html page itself. A code that would use the response sent by the server. Do you know of a way?

Comment: You can run this code in a browser just fine. The [XMLHttpRequest object has a getAllResponseHeaders() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#getAllResponseHeaders()) you can use to retrieve the headers as a newline delimited string.